# Executing method from markup

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set some javascript data (json) in my markup by calling a method in my codebehind file. The markup looks like this:

`Line 12:     var businessTypes = "<%=GetBusinessTypes(); %>";`

The method is executed and it returns string value but then this exceptions pops out

> CS1026: ) expected

redlining the Line 12 shown above.

Comment: Could you post some more surrounding code? Often times it's the code around the line that's the problem, not the actual line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's because you're including a semicolon after the method call. The output tags "<%= %>" essentially wrap your code with `Response.Write(...);`

Try:

```
var businessTypes = "<%= GetBusinessTypes() %>";
```

Comment: Yup, semicolon was the problem. Thanks